# Getting content from a referenced post

Tags: php, the-content

I have the following, which is successfully pulling the title, thumbnail, and custom field data (YouTube link) from a referenced post, but the content displayed is that of the parent:

```
function woo_videos_tab_content() {
$posts = get_field('videos');
if( $posts ): ?>
    <div class="row">
    <?php foreach( $posts as $p ): ?>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
        <a data-remodal-target="modal-<?php echo $p->ID; ?>" class="video-link" title="<?php echo get_the_title( $p->ID ); ?>" >
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $p->ID, 'video-thumb' ); ?>
            <i class="fa fa-youtube-play fa-4x"></i>
        </a>
        <h4><?php echo get_the_title( $p->ID ); ?></h4>

        // Issue with the line below
        <?php echo get_the_content( $p->ID ); ?>

        <div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="modal-<?php echo $p->ID; ?>">
            <button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close"></button>
            <h2><?php echo get_the_title( $p->ID ); ?></h2>
            <iframe src="<?php the_field('youtube_link', $p->ID); ?>?enablejsapi=1&version=3" allowfullscreen="" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowscriptaccess="always"></iframe>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php endif;
}
```

Should I be pulling the content via another method? I had assumed what worked for title / thumbnail / custom field would work for the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function [`get_the_content`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content) doesn't take `post_ID` as param. It has 2 params:

- `$more_link_text` - (string) (optional) Content for when there is
  more text.
- `$stripteaser` - (boolean) (optional) Strip teaser content
  before the more text.

So you can't use it as in your code `get_the_content( $p->ID );` - this will get content of current post and use `$p->ID` as more link text.

So how to get the content of any post based on post ID?

You can use [`get_post_field`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_field) function:

```
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', get_post_field( 'post_content', $p->ID ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the methods with incorrect parameter.

First of all, get_the_content function doesn't take id of the post as parameter.
[here is the ref](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content)

Second, in the loop, you are using has_post_thumbnail without parameter. In that case, you must use the_post() method, because it actually change the global post variable in the loop.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean about get_the_content. Regarding your second point, I'm not following. Is it relevant to the question (aside from being accurate)? I have added more context to the code, as I thought I should include the whole function for clarity.

Comment: @user2265915 yes, get_the_content uses global post variable as well, so that doesn't need post id. So if you use get_the_content without the_post(),  it won't work properly.